# Missing immediate certificate but still valid

Tags: apache, certificate

I have this certificate on my server:

DigiCert -> DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-3 -> wildcard.mydomain.com

And if "DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-3" is not installed on the client machine I will get a error from the browser that is server certificate is not valid. If I installed it manually it's working fine.

But if I go to i.e. https://github.com I can see this certificate chain in the browser:

DigiCert -> DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1 -> github.com

If I check in my user certificate store via certmgr.msc I can find the Root CA (DigiCert) but not the immediate certificate. Why is this working?

Maybe I can setup Apache to send the immediate certificate to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SSLCertificateChainFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) to provide the intermediate certificates to the browser.